# Newtek NDI Stream within a webpage / WebGL / Three.js

Tags: typescript, three.js, streaming, webgl

I need to implement [a NDI stream](https://www.newtek.com/ndi/sdk/) into a website, formerly into a three.js [application](https://openmapper.ch).

All I found was the node.js implementation from [streampunk](https://github.com/Streampunk/grandiose) which does not run on Linux.

I could not find any information on how to achieve this. Can someone point me into the right direction ?